# jquery/datepicker/alert "invalid date' on manual entry

Tags: jquery

i have some users who want to be able to manually enter a date and also have the datepicker calendar available.  I want it to alert me if the date is not in a date format.

for example, 
entery: 010101 would format the date to 01/01/01 on exit but
01010101 would alert "invalid date"

i have searched parsedate, and foramtdate and have not found a working example of either and after several attempts to get it to alert me i have failed,

please some thought from the group?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $(function() {
    $( '#sbDinput' ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

    var myDate=$('#sbDinput').val()

     alert($.datepicker.parseDate( "dd/mm/yy", myDate ))


        }
    });
});
 $('#amwDinput0').datepicker();
 $('#amwDinput1').datepicker();
 $('#amwDinput2').datepicker();
 $('#amwDinput3').datepicker();
```

Comment: I thought all the responsible developers stopped using two-digit years by 1995.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it by hand - make sure that the `myDate` has a length of `6`, then split it into the appropriate chunks, like this:

```
if(myDate.length === 6) {
    day = myDate.substring(0, 2);
    month = myDate.substring(2, 4);
    year = myDate.substring(4);
    alert($.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", day + "/" + month + "/" + year));
} else { 
    alert("Invalid Date");
}
```

Comment: I will go this route, and also check for '/' as well, i was hoping it would do it i guess i got lost in that,